# How to prevent DOM XSS Vulnerability for this script -

Tags: appexchange, dom, xss, stored-xss

{!tableData} is Server variable.

```
<script> 
$('.content').html("{!tableData}"); ... 
</script>
```

"{!tableData}" is having HTML data.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to encode using JSENCODE and HTMLENCODE .

Here is what you can do

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $('.content').html("{!JSINHTMLENCODE(tableData)}"); ... 
</script>
```